# React Context Decorator/Subscriber?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Edit: Perhaps this could be referenced as a context subscriber?**

I'm not even sure if this is the right concept that I'm trying to achieve. I want to be able to create a component that does the dirty work and just attaches context to the component that can the be consumed..

I've tried to find anything similar with no luck, which, leads me to believe I am not thinking of the right *literal* context of what it is I'm doing...

I've tried something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
export const Context = React.createContext();

export class ContextProvider extends Component {
state = {
    scanning: false
};

render() {
    return (
        <Context.Provider
            value={{
                state: this.state,
                handleClick: () => this.setState({
                    scanning: !this.state.scanning
                })
            }}
        >
            {this.props.children}
        </Context.Provider>
    );
}
}
```

And I trying to make it work with this..

```
import React from "react";
import { Context } from "./Context";

const WithContext = (children) => (props) => {
    return (
        <Context.Consumer>
            { state  => (<children {...props} context={state} />) }
        </Context.Consumer>
    )
};
```

and then consuming with...

```
...
<WithContext>
    <MyComponent />
</WithContext>
...
```

But, it just seems to fail or states that I'm returning a function instead of a react component..

Answer (score 1):

Your `WithContext` component will not work like that... It needs to be a function that has the same functionality as the `render` function. like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { Context } from "./Context";

const WithContext = ({ children, ...props }) => (
  <Context.Consumer>{state  => React.Children.map(children, (child) => (
    React.cloneElement(child, { context: state }) 
  ))}</Context.Consumer>
);
```

note that we traverse every direct child of the `withContext` children using `React.Children.map` ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren)) and add a `context` prop to them by making use of `React.cloneElement` ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)). This keeps the child component's original props and shallow merges them into the second parameter passed to the function.

Comment: What would I use to reference the context within that new component?

Comment: the `MyComponent` component will have a prop named `context`, and that prop will have everything you set on your context. On your specific case, it will be an object with `state` and `handleClick` keys, as you declared on the `Context.js` file. Use `this.props.context.state` for example to get the object `{ scanning: false }`.

Comment: Weird, I just keep getting errors stating that it's undefined.. but, I can see it in the react dev tools :/

Answer (score -1):

There are a bunch of little errors in your code for using context... Here is a complete example...

Let's say we have a structure where we have `App.js -> Parent.js -> Child.js` components... Instead of passing the data via props from App to Parent to Child we want to make use of the context API and avoid the prop drilling and have the Child consume the data directly...

Here is what that will look like:

context.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const Context = React.createContext();

export class Provider extends React.Component {
  state = { name: 'Bob', age: 20 };

  handleGrowUp = () => {
    this.setState({ age: this.state.age + 1 });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider
        value={{
          state: {
            ...this.state,
          },
          actions: {
            growUp: this.handleGrowUp,
          },
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export const Consumer = Context.Consumer;
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Parent from './Parent';

import { Provider } from './context';

const App = () => (
  <Provider>
    <Parent />
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

Parent.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Child from './Child';

const Parent = () => (
  <div>
    <Child />
  </div>
);

export default Parent;
```

Child.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Consumer } from './context';

const Child = () => (
  <div>
    <Consumer>
      {value => (
        <div>
          <p>{value.state.name}</p>
          <p>{value.state.age}</p>
          <button onClick={value.actions.growUp}>Grow Up</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </Consumer>
  </div>
);

export default Child;
```

Here is a working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/9z06xzlyly

Comment: I understand how context works, correct me if I'm wrong, but, I don't think this is what I'm looking for or was constructive to the question?

Comment: @BryceSnyder - I see you've updated the question... Maybe I didn't understand the question originally... The example I provided as it states should get you going... As I understand it now - You're looking to create a HOC... Looks like Sergio answered that...

Comment: @BryceSnyder - also, the reason I decided to give a full demo for the context is because there are errors in your code: if you are doing `export class ContextProvider extends Component` then you should do `<Context. ContextProvider>` in your render and not `<Context.Provider>` and a bunch of other little things... which leads me to believe that you do not understand how context works - hence the complete example...

Comment: That was a spelling mistake on my part.

Comment: @BryceSnyder - I just tried to help... if you found it useful - great, if not that’s ok too...

Comment: I appreciate it!